# Devise session create - slow select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've been looking at some of the slowest performing queries in the database  of our rails4 app, and one of them that crops up is a user select during the session create performed by Devise.

```
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`remember_token` = '12345'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

This query takes anywhere between 1 and 2 seconds to run as the table is large.

Obviously I can speed that up hugely by only retrieving the indexed field (the id) at which point the query time drops to milliseconds.

Is it possible to amend the queries that devise is running, or optimise it another way, as this is obviously slowing down the login process for our users?

Comment: Which indexes do you have in your table? If using MySQL, please append the result of the `explain` statement on that method.

Comment: Can you add indexes for the rest of the fields too... ?